# How to log information on session_start

Tags: asp.net

I want to log on browser information on a session_start event but, of course in global.asax I can't use

```
Request.Browser
```

how should I set it up?

Comment: why do you want to log it on Session Start?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: Why not?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - hehe. my question really was why would you want to log it there or find out the browser of the user on the session rather than somewhere a little more "relevant" i.e page load events instead of specific to session state handling events. that's all.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: for example because you don't want to log it on e very postback on every page. It's also handy to put this code on a single place instead of in every `Page_Load`.

Comment: understood - sorry, mine was an example, that's all. I guess my angle was "what is the core fundamental problem here that concerns Request.Browser?". Anyway - +1 on your point and example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Session_Start` in the [`global.asax` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = base.Context;
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpBrowserCapabilities browserCapabilities = request.Browser;
    // log, for example the browser's name:
    string browserName = browserCapabilities.Browser; // Firefox in my case
}
```

The `Session_Start` event is fired the first time when a user’s session is started. This typically contains for session initialization logic code.

[Working with the ASP.NET Global.asax file](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/)

Comment: I must admit that i have overlooked that you already knew about the global.asax. However, glad i could help :)